# OnChange Event on CF7 Dropdowns [Select]

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make dependent date dropdowns for my wordpress Website.
I have prepared code for Html website using Jquery . It is working fine and giving desirable output but I am unable to know how to implement same thing in Wordpress.

As I am new to Wordpress I am unable to find the customization in CF7.

Please, help if anybody know, Below is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC > 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Time Dependent Dropdowns</title> 
</head>
<body>
 <select id="arrival-time-list" onchange="ChangeSecondList(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="arrival">
<option value="">Select arrival time</option>
<option value="8:00am">8:00am</option>
<option value="8:15am">8:15am</option>
<option value="8:30am">8:30am</option>
<option value="8:45am">8:45am</option>
<option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
<option value="9:15am">9:15am</option>
<option value="9:30am">9:30am</option>
<option value="9:45am">9:45am</option>
<option value="10:00am">10:00am</option>
<option value="10:15am">10:15am</option>
<option value="10:30am">10:30am</option>
<option value="10:45am">10:45am</option>
<option value="11:00am">11:00am</option>
<option value="11:15am">11:15am</option>
<option value="11:30am">11:30am</option>
<option value="11:45am">11:45am</option>
<option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
<option value="12:15pm">12:15pm</option>
<option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
<option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
<option value="1:00pm">1:00pm</option>
<option value="1:15pm">1:15pm</option>
<option value="1:30pm">1:30pm</option>
<option value="1:45pm">1:45pm</option>
<option value="2:00am">2:00am</option>
<option value="2:15am">2:15am</option>
<option value="2:30pm">2:30pm</option>
<option value="2:45pm">2:45pm</option>
<option value="3:00pm">3:00pm</option>
<option value="3:15pm">3:15pm</option>
<option value="3:30pm">3:30pm</option>
<option value="3:45pm">3:45pm</option>
<option value="4:00pm">4:00pm</option>
<option value="4:15pm">4:15pm</option>
<option value="4:30pm">4:30pm</option>
<option value="4:45pm">4:45pm</option>
<option value="5:00pm">5:00pm</option>
<option value="5:15pm">5:15pm</option>
<option value="5:30pm">5:30pm</option>
<option value="5:45pm">5:45pm</option>
<option value="6:00pm">6:00pm</option>
<option value="6:15pm">6:15pm</option>
<option value="6:30pm">6:30pm</option>
<option value="6:45pm">6:45pm</option>
<option value="7:00pm">7:00pm</option>
</select>
<div id="static-list-div" style="display:block;">
<select>
<option>&#8679; Select an arrival time</option>
<option value="">Select arrival time</option>
<option value="8:00am">8:00am</option>
<option value="8:15am">8:15am</option>
<option value="8:30am">8:30am</option>
<option value="8:45am">8:45am</option>
<option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
<option value="9:15am">9:15am</option>
<option value="9:30am">9:30am</option>
<option value="9:45am">9:45am</option>
<option value="10:00am">10:00am</option>
<option value="10:15am">10:15am</option>
<option value="10:30am">10:30am</option>
<option value="10:45am">10:45am</option>
<option value="11:00am">11:00am</option>
<option value="11:15am">11:15am</option>
<option value="11:30am">11:30am</option>
<option value="11:45am">11:45am</option>
<option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
<option value="12:15pm">12:15pm</option>
<option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
<option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
<option value="1:00pm">1:00pm</option>
<option value="1:15pm">1:15pm</option>
<option value="1:30pm">1:30pm</option>
<option value="1:45pm">1:45pm</option>
<option value="2:00am">2:00am</option>
<option value="2:15am">2:15am</option>
<option value="2:30pm">2:30pm</option>
<option value="2:45pm">2:45pm</option>
<option value="3:00pm">3:00pm</option>
<option value="3:15pm">3:15pm</option>
<option value="3:30pm">3:30pm</option>
<option value="3:45pm">3:45pm</option>
<option value="4:00pm">4:00pm</option>
<option value="4:15pm">4:15pm</option>
<option value="4:30pm">4:30pm</option>
<option value="4:45pm">4:45pm</option>
<option value="5:00pm">5:00pm</option>
<option value="5:15pm">5:15pm</option>
<option value="5:30pm">5:30pm</option>
<option value="5:45pm">5:45pm</option>
<option value="6:00pm">6:00pm</option>
<option value="6:15pm">6:15pm</option>
<option value="6:30pm">6:30pm</option>
<option value="6:45pm">6:45pm</option>
<option value="7:00pm">7:00pm</option>
<option>&#8679; from the above dropdown.</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="dynamic-list-div" style="display:none;">
<select id="dynamic-list" name="serving">
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeSecondList(value)
{
   if( value.length )
   {
      document.getElementById("static-list-div").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("dynamic-list-div").style.display = "block";
      var dropid = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
      var ta = value.split(":");
      var hour = parseInt(ta[0]);
      var minute = parseInt(ta[1].replace(/\D/g,""));
      var apm = ta[1].replace(/\d/g,"");
      for( var i=0; i<3; i++ )
      {
         hour += 2;
         if( minute > 59 )
         {
            hour++;
            minute -= 60;
            if( hour > 11 )
            {
               apm = apm.replace(/a/,'p');
               apm = apm.replace(/A/,'P');
            }
         }
         if( hour > 12 ) { hour -= 12; }
         if( minute < 10 ) { minute = "0"+minute; }
         var valuetext = hour + ":" + minute + apm;
         dropid.options[i].text = valuetext;
         dropid.options[i].value = valuetext;
         minute = parseInt(minute);
      }
      dropid.options[0].selected = true;
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById("static-list-div").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("dynamic-list-div").style.display = "none";
   }
}

ChangeSecondList(document.getElementById("arrival-time-list").options[document.getElementById("arrival-time-list").selectedIndex].value);
</script>
 </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any Custom Plugin? What did you try so far?

Comment: Could you also please share any screenshots of the feature you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you -- +1 for this if you understand.
I dont't know about your script and this code just generate with CF7.

#Firstly add functions into function.php file .

You can create custom tag with your custom html data and use it into cf7 as a shortcode/tag like this.

```
// create a custom clock tag for cf7.
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'your_custom_cf_code' );
function your_custom_cf_code() {

wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'clock', 'your_custom_cf_data' ); // this is your custom callback function

 // "clock" is the type of the form-tag 
 }
```

// this is your callback function with your custom html

```
function your_custom_cf_data(){
echo '<select id="arrival-time-list" onchange="ChangeSecondList(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="arrival">
<option value="">Select arrival time</option>
<option value="8:00am">8:00am</option>
<option value="8:15am">8:15am</option>
<option value="8:30am">8:30am</option>
<option value="8:45am">8:45am</option>
<option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
<option value="9:15am">9:15am</option>
<option value="9:30am">9:30am</option>
<option value="9:45am">9:45am</option>
<option value="10:00am">10:00am</option>
<option value="10:15am">10:15am</option>
<option value="10:30am">10:30am</option>
<option value="10:45am">10:45am</option>
<option value="11:00am">11:00am</option>
<option value="11:15am">11:15am</option>
<option value="11:30am">11:30am</option>
<option value="11:45am">11:45am</option>
<option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
<option value="12:15pm">12:15pm</option>
<option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
<option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
<option value="1:00pm">1:00pm</option>
<option value="1:15pm">1:15pm</option>
<option value="1:30pm">1:30pm</option>
<option value="1:45pm">1:45pm</option>
<option value="2:00am">2:00am</option>
<option value="2:15am">2:15am</option>
<option value="2:30pm">2:30pm</option>
<option value="2:45pm">2:45pm</option>
<option value="3:00pm">3:00pm</option>
<option value="3:15pm">3:15pm</option>
<option value="3:30pm">3:30pm</option>
<option value="3:45pm">3:45pm</option>
<option value="4:00pm">4:00pm</option>
<option value="4:15pm">4:15pm</option>
<option value="4:30pm">4:30pm</option>
<option value="4:45pm">4:45pm</option>
<option value="5:00pm">5:00pm</option>
<option value="5:15pm">5:15pm</option>
<option value="5:30pm">5:30pm</option>
<option value="5:45pm">5:45pm</option>
<option value="6:00pm">6:00pm</option>
<option value="6:15pm">6:15pm</option>
<option value="6:30pm">6:30pm</option>
<option value="6:45pm">6:45pm</option>
<option value="7:00pm">7:00pm</option>
</select>
<div id="static-list-div" style="display:block;">
<select>
<option>&#8679; Select an arrival time</option>
<option value="">Select arrival time</option>
<option value="8:00am">8:00am</option>
<option value="8:15am">8:15am</option>
<option value="8:30am">8:30am</option>
<option value="8:45am">8:45am</option>
<option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
<option value="9:15am">9:15am</option>
<option value="9:30am">9:30am</option>
<option value="9:45am">9:45am</option>
<option value="10:00am">10:00am</option>
<option value="10:15am">10:15am</option>
<option value="10:30am">10:30am</option>
<option value="10:45am">10:45am</option>
<option value="11:00am">11:00am</option>
<option value="11:15am">11:15am</option>
<option value="11:30am">11:30am</option>
<option value="11:45am">11:45am</option>
<option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
<option value="12:15pm">12:15pm</option>
<option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
<option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
<option value="1:00pm">1:00pm</option>
<option value="1:15pm">1:15pm</option>
<option value="1:30pm">1:30pm</option>
<option value="1:45pm">1:45pm</option>
<option value="2:00am">2:00am</option>
<option value="2:15am">2:15am</option>
<option value="2:30pm">2:30pm</option>
<option value="2:45pm">2:45pm</option>
<option value="3:00pm">3:00pm</option>
<option value="3:15pm">3:15pm</option>
<option value="3:30pm">3:30pm</option>
<option value="3:45pm">3:45pm</option>
<option value="4:00pm">4:00pm</option>
<option value="4:15pm">4:15pm</option>
<option value="4:30pm">4:30pm</option>
<option value="4:45pm">4:45pm</option>
<option value="5:00pm">5:00pm</option>
<option value="5:15pm">5:15pm</option>
<option value="5:30pm">5:30pm</option>
<option value="5:45pm">5:45pm</option>
<option value="6:00pm">6:00pm</option>
<option value="6:15pm">6:15pm</option>
<option value="6:30pm">6:30pm</option>
<option value="6:45pm">6:45pm</option>
<option value="7:00pm">7:00pm</option>
<option>&#8679; from the above dropdown.</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="dynamic-list-div" style="display:none;">
<select id="dynamic-list" name="serving">
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</div>';
}
```

//this is your custom script

```
 add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeSecondList(value)
{
   if( value.length )
   {
      document.getElementById("static-list-div").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("dynamic-list-div").style.display = "block";
      var dropid = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
      var ta = value.split(":");
      var hour = parseInt(ta[0]);
      var minute = parseInt(ta[1].replace(/\D/g,""));
      var apm = ta[1].replace(/\d/g,"");
      for( var i=0; i<3; i++ )
      {
         hour += 2;
         if( minute > 59 )
         {
            hour++;
            minute -= 60;
            if( hour > 11 )
            {
               apm = apm.replace(/a/,'p');
               apm = apm.replace(/A/,'P');
            }
         }
         if( hour > 12 ) { hour -= 12; }
         if( minute < 10 ) { minute = "0"+minute; }
         var valuetext = hour + ":" + minute + apm;
         dropid.options[i].text = valuetext;
         dropid.options[i].value = valuetext;
         minute = parseInt(minute);
      }
      dropid.options[0].selected = true;
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById("static-list-div").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("dynamic-list-div").style.display = "none";
   }
}

ChangeSecondList(document.getElementById("arrival-time-list").options[document.getElementById("arrival-time-list").selectedIndex].value);
</script>
<?php ?>
```

//after that put your custom [clock] tag into contact form 7

## [clock] tag into CF7

That's it.

Comment: Thanks , for your affords. I am trying to make dependent dropdowns for time. Such as- If a user select 10:00 a.m from first dropdown, second dropdown will automatically fetch 10:15 a.m.  The above attached code is working fine in Html but I am unable to understand how to implement the same in contact form 7 in wordpress.

Comment: Try above code , this will add your all code in contact form 7, it is a working code,only do copy and page in function.php and add shordtcode [clock] in contact form 7

Comment: Please help to include it within <form> markup. shortcode is working but now considering it within <form>

Comment: If you added the shortcode in CF7,The shortcode is already added in contact form 7, check in your browser console and inspect them.
If my answer is correct mark as correct answer for others user also.

Comment: For any other query raise your question again in new.

Comment: The answer you gave is good for static purpose but I need to make a dynamic dependent dropdown which can be handled through cf7 in backend.So, the answer is not helpful for me.

Comment: for dynamic the field you need to create a customposttype and create a meta boxes into it , make the field dynamic into your function your_custom_cf_data(){} this function by loop .

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer of one line.We can do the same using the below line of jquery:$('#arrival-time-list'). attr("onchange", "ChangeSecondList(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)");

Comment: No worries :) happy coding